# Como funciona hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring

Quais são os values que posso utilizar nessa propiedade? ex: Update

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

Como funciona? Quando devo utilizar? é uma boa prática?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As opções são essas:

- `validate`: validar o schema, não faz mudanças no banco de dados.
- `update`: faz update o schema.
- `create`: cria o schema, destruindo dados anteriores.
- `create-drop`: drop o schema quando ao terminar a sessão.

Ai você tem que avaliar o que é melhor para seu projeto, geralmente eu utilizo o `update`.

Link da resposta no SOen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/5165064)

Answer (score 5):

- #### Como funciona?

Respondida pelo nosso amigo [Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20706/rafael).

- #### Quando devo utilizar?

Isso é um pouco ambíguo, pois pode desencadear boas discussões, mas é bom pensar nisso como dar responsabilidade a uma tecnologia que teoricamente vai cuidar de todas as ações de desenvolvimento no database.

*Será que é uma boa idéia deixar acontecer de forma automática, a criação, atualização ou remoção de qualquer entidade pelo Hibernate?*

Não, por mais que o todo o desenvolvimento para o database forme o mesmo codebase, não significa que a automatização de um sobre o outro irá funcionar. Validar seus scripts de uma forma manual é sempre uma forma mais segura para o desenvolvimento. Nunca utilize isso em produção, pode ser um erro fatal.

Mas podemos falar em contexto, se o seu contexto é fazer um projeto próprio de estudo e teste, talvez sim, mas eu não acredito que seja uma boa prática. Em minha experiência com ferramentas que costumam fazer algo relacionado a desenvolvimento de forma automática, tendem a falhar miseravelmente.

- #### é uma boa prática?

Não. Vejo como uma péssima prática, tanto do lado do desenvolvedor quanto do lado do cliente que vai utilizar o produto. Dar responsabilidades de desenvolvimento a qualquer ferramenta não é uma boa prática. Boa prática é você ter total controle do produto, desde a forma como é entregue, até a sua arquitetura e code quality. Pense o quão simples é para o hibernate replicar uma linha de código errada sua para o database e dessa forma causar o caos e isso esteve totalmente fora do seu alcance.

Mas como falei, podemos gerar boas discussões, pois se formos focar em boas práticas não utilizaríamos ORM, pois é com certeza um anti-pattern para Orientação a Objetos.

Answer (score -2):

Esta é a lista completa:

validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
update: update the schema.
create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.
none: does nothing with the schema, makes no changes to the database

Comment: No caso ai, o ideal é adotar none, e montar o esquema de tabelas manualmente via ddl.