# Trabalhando com o arquivo application.properties

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Veja meu arquivo application..properties:

```
 spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
  spring.datasource.platform=postgres
  spring.jpa.show-sql=true
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
  spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/money?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
  spring.datasource.username=postgres
  spring.datasource.password=1234
```

O que está acontecendo é que toda vez quando vou executar o projeto ele dá um drop na tabela e depois criar a tabela tudo de novo, e com isso ele apaga todos os registros que existem no banco como pode ver abaixo;

Isso abaixo é um log do SpringTools, é porque meu projeto é um **Spring Boot**

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists categoria cascade
Hibernate: create table categoria (codigo  bigserial not null, nome varchar(255), primary key (codigo))
[2m2017-11-14 13:24:14.127[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4076[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Como faço para configurar o arquivo pra não fazer isso?

Eu tentei com esse trecho de código, mas não tive sucesso.

```
?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: [Como funciona hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90729/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, essa propriedade não deve estar com esse valor:

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Neste caso ele sempre vai "dropar" a tabela e recriar. Recomendo se você quiser manter os dados remover essa propriedade do seu properties(comente)

Answer (score -1):

Você também pode usar outra configuração nessa linha de código. Por exemplo:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Dessa forma os dados ficam armazenados e você só atualiza tabelas e campos que sofrerem alguma alteração.