# Hibernate não está criando ou atualizando as tabelas do BD

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Tenho as classes

beans.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

<scan>
    <exclude name="com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService"/>
</scan>

</beans>
```

validation.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration 
validation-configuration-1.1.xsd"
version="1.1">
<executable-validation enabled="false" />
```

peristence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">



<!-- LOCAL (DEFAULT) -->
<persistence-unit name="postgreSQL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />


        <!-- LOCAL -->

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rreefstore" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="dsv" />


        <!-- PRODUÇÃO -->
        <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://urlServer:5432/tfBestJob" 
            /> <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="adminbj" /> <property 
            name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="senha" /> -->


        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Pedido.java

```
   package br.com.rreefstore.model.entity;

   import java.util.Calendar;

   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;
   import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

   /**
    * @author Tiago Ferezin
    *
    */
   @Entity
   @Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "codigoPedido", name = "uk_codigoPedido") })
   public class Pedido extends AEntity<Pedido> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long idPedido;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String codigoPedido;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer quantidade;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Calendar dataCriacao;

private Calendar dataDesativacao;

public Pedido() {

}

/**
 * @return the idPedido
 */
public Long getIdPedido() {
    return idPedido;
}

/**
 * @param idPedido the idPedido to set
 */
public void setIdPedido(Long idPedido) {
    this.idPedido = idPedido;
}

/**
 * @return the codigoPedido
 */
public String getCodigoPedido() {
    return codigoPedido;
}

/**
 * @param codigoPedido the codigoPedido to set
 */
public void setCodigoPedido(String codigoPedido) {
    this.codigoPedido = codigoPedido;
}

/**
 * @return the quantidade
 */
public Integer getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

/**
 * @param quantidade the quantidade to set
 */
public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

/**
 * @return the dataCriacao
 */
public Calendar getDataCriacao() {
    return dataCriacao;
}

/**
 * @param dataCriacao the dataCriacao to set
 */
public void setDataCriacao(Calendar dataCriacao) {
    this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
}

@Override
public Long getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return idPedido;
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.idPedido = id;
}

@Override
public boolean isDeleted() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Calendar getDataDesativacao() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataDesativacao;
}

@Override
public void setDataDesativacao(Calendar dataDesativacao) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.dataDesativacao = dataDesativacao;
}

}
```

A `EntityManager` roda corretamente, e não é nula.

Quando rodo o método de inserção aparece o seguinte erro:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "pedido" does not exist

Problema que até antes de criar essa classe `Pedido.java`, todo o sistema rodava normal, o banco atualizava as tabelas e as que não tinha, era criada automaticamente pelo hibernate, e agora ele não cria e nem atualiza nenhuma tabela.

Segue abaixo a Stacktrace, lembrando que nenhuma classe se relaciona com `Pedido.java`.

> ```
> Hibernate: 
>     insert 
>     into
>         Pedido
>         (dataCriacao, dataDesativacao, quantidade) 
>     values
>         (?, ?, ?)
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.dao.GenericDAO.create(GenericDAO.java:60)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.dao.factory.GenericDAOFactory.create(GenericDAOFactory.java:26)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.test.model.entity.PedidoTestNG.criacao(PedidoTestNG.java:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
>     at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>     at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>     ... 27 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "pedido" does not exist
>   Posição: 13
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     ... 48 more
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.dao.GenericDAO.create(GenericDAO.java:60)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.dao.factory.GenericDAOFactory.create(GenericDAOFactory.java:26)
>     at br.com.rreefstore.test.model.entity.PedidoTestNG.criacao(PedidoTestNG.java:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
>     at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>     at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>     ... 27 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "pedido" does not exist
>   Posição: 13
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     ... 48 more
> ```

Como solucionar isso?

Lembrando que esse erro ocorre com todas as classes que crio após a primeira execução, criei `Pessoa.java` e apontou:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "pessoa" does not exist

Qual solução para o problema?

PS: Código disponível em:

[Projeto disponível no Github](https://github.com/tiagoferezin/RibeiraoReef)

Comment: Não houve uma resposta

Comment: Existe alguma classe que possua um relacionamento com a classe `Pedido`? Caso haja, adicione-a e coloque a *stack trace* inteira por favor.

Comment: @FelipeMarinho coloquei a stack trace no anunciado acima, editei a pergunta pra colocar mais detalhes, e não ha nenhuma classe que tem o relacionamento com `Pedido` ajude por favor

Comment: Talvez o Hibernate esteja criando as tabelas com a inicial maiúscula e na hora de executar qualquer outro *statement* esteja usando letras minúsculas. Verifique se as tabelas estão com a inicial maiúscula no banco. Caso estejam, tente informar na anotação `@Table` o `name` das tabelas com letra minúscula.

Comment: @FelipeMarinho, infelizmente eu tenho o banco criado, mas o hibernate nem esta criando as tabelas, fiz a informação do `@Table(name="pedido")` na classe `Pedido.java` e o erro persiste.

Comment: Ele não está criando nenhuma tabela? Nesse caso ele deveria lançar alguma exceção indicando o motivo no momento da inicialização da sua aplicação.

Comment: Estou rodando no TestNG e ta dando esse problema e realmente nao esta criando nenhuma tabela, na verdade ate estava criando as tabelas certo, mas parou de uma hora pra outra e comecou esse erro @FelipeMarinho

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77088/discussion-between-tiago-ferezin-and-felipe-marinho).

Comment: Em que pasta o `persistence.xml` está localizado? Vejo que você está executando ele em um contexto de teste, então pode ser que o hibernate o esteja procurando na pasta errada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa o `persistence.xml` está localizado na pasta `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

Comment: Consegue passar o commando *DDL* da criaçao da tabela pedido no Postgre?

Comment: @TiagoFerezin Tente copiar e colar ele (duplicando, não é para apagar o original) para `src/test/resources/META-INF/`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, não entendi sua pergunta, poderia reformulá-la? Grato

Comment: @VictorStafusa, segui o que me pediu e apontou outro erro `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: br.com.rreefstore.model.entity.Pedido`

Comment: @TiagoFerezin, estou pedindo para você atualizar a pergunta com o comando `CREATE TABLE` + código criação de quaisquer *constraints*, e.g, `uk_codigoPedido`, a *Primary Key*, etc da tabela `Pedido`. Estou desconfiado que sua tabela não foi criada, ou foi criada de maneira errada. `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` tem seus problemas. Se é um ambiente local e os dados não interessam para ti talvez valha a pena tentar com `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` (isso vai  *dropar* seu *schema*, então tome cuidado)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, na verdade o hibernate não está realmente criando as tabelas, se entrar no banco so vai ter as tabelas anteriores e a `create-drop` não me é interessante pois é um ecommerce

Comment: Tenteo `create-drop` em um schema novo no banco só para ver se a tabela é devidamente criada.  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` também não é desejável para ambientes além da máquina do desenvolvedor. Você em breve precisará de uma política de rastreamento / migração / evolução de dados e esbarrará em ferramentas como Liquibase ou Flyway como alternativas mais robustas ao mecanismo de geração de comandos ddl do Hibernate.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly o `create-drop` esta rodando normal, ele cria e drop as tabelas, o `update` ele cria as tabelas somente na primeira vez, na segunda, caso eu delete uma tabela, ele nao atualiza e nem cria ela novamente.

Comment: Olá Tiago, se o `create-drop` está criando a tabela `pedido` como esperado então você realmente não tem nenhum problema no código acima, o problema é a politica de `update`. Eu entendo que sua espectativa com essa pergunta era de dar uma sobrevida à simplicidade do `hbm2ddl.auto` mas infelizmente o melhor conselho que tenho para te dar é que migre para uma solução mais robusta como [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org) ou [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org). Vale a Pena fazer isso enquanto o *schema* ainda é razoavelmente pequeno.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly e como eu implementaria o `Flyway` no meu projeto?

Comment: Olá Tiago, isso vale uma pergunta nova. Mas de forma bem resumida, você vai exportar todo o seu `SCHEMA` atual para um arquivo SQL. Essa vai ser a primeira "migração". Daí para frente cada modificação nas suas entidades  deverá ser acompanhada de uma  nova "migração" (arquivo  SQL alterando 
colunas, adicionando novas tabelas, etc). O Flyway mantém um histórico das migrações  aplicadas em  cada ambiente  e torna fácil  o processo de evolução 
do *schema*. De uma olhada na [documentação](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline) para ter uma ideia sobre o que isso envolve.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly coloquei como uma pergunta essa questão no  [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297326/como-implementar-flyway-num-projeto-javaee-maven-com-hibernate-vraptor-e-jpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo `hibernate.cfg.xml`, verifique a linha:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

Opções:

- `validate`: validar o schema, não faz mudanças no banco de dados.
- `update`: faz update o schema.
- `create`: cria o schema, destruindo dados anteriores.
- `create-drop`: drop o schema quando ao terminar a sessão.

[Referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90723/como-funciona-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto)

Comment: Eu não estou usando o hibernate.cfg.xml, as configurações estão todas no persistence.xml, e rodava normal, na empresa que trabalhava tambem nao usava o hibernate.cfg.xml e tinhamos algumas aplicações web rodando normal.

Comment: E essa configuração já está constando no `persistence.xml` , conforme pode verificar `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />`

Comment: Essa resposta não resolveu o problema amigo