# Como implementar Flyway num projeto JavaEE Maven com Hibernate, vRaptor e JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven, flyway

Em um projeto Maven, JPA, com Hibernate e vRaptor integrados, como implementar de forma fácil e eficaz, o [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)?

Implementando isso, meu banco irá atualizar como era no desenvolvimento o

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

ou não?

Comment: A pergunta é boa, não entendo os votos para fechar. Tiago, tentou configurar o Maven para usar o plugin `flyway-maven-plugin`? Você pode configurar este plugin para ele ser executado em uma das etapas do Maven. Creio que possa configurar ele para ser executado antes de subir sua aplicação (se estiver subindo via Maven). Assim, ele atuaria de forma similar ao `update` do `hbm2ddl`

Comment: @Dherik e como faria essa configuração?

Comment: Gostaria de saber o motivo por quererem que eu feche essa questão sendo que é bem relevante e não encontrei nada dessa informação na internet

Comment: Não fechem por favor. Eu vou escrever uma resposta assim que conseguir sentar um pouco em frente ao PC. Outras respostas e, é claro, são muito bem vindas. Tiago, acho que o pessoal está votando para fechar devido ao "maneira fácil e eficaz de implementar". Dá a impressão que você quer uma resposta pronta e não está pondo esforço o suficiente de pesquisa na pergunta. Adiantando a resposta , o Flyway é uma tecnologia ortogonal às outras mencionadas e ela não funciona exatamente como o hbm2ddl (ferramenta de prototipação) e sim como um "Git" para bancos de dados (ferramenta de versionamento).

Comment: Para complementar o Anthony, Tiago o seu banco de dados sempre será a execução sequencial de todos os scripts do flywaydb em ordem cronologica, nunca será a aplicação somente de parte ou do último script.

Comment: @FlávioGranato, sim entendo, mas teria um tutorial bom pra implementação do mesmo no projeto maven com hibernate e vraptor? Abri a questão mais para disponibilizar isso, e teria algum design pra essa implementação?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly conseguiu?

Comment: Oi Tiago, perdão, ainda não consegui terminar de escrever a resposta, mas estou trabalhando nela. Perdão pela demora.